# Filter an array by category and keyword

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to filter an array by the category of an item and by its title.
For example, I have  a  few jobs, each job is an object, containing a job title and an array of categort, so:

```js
const category = [
  'Web designer',
  'App developer',
  'Cleaning',
  'Designer',
];
const [userSelectedCategory, setUserSelectedCategory] = useState([]);
const jobs = [
  {
    title: 'Job 1',
    category: ['Web designer', 'App developer'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Job 2',
    category: ['Cleaning', 'Web Designer'],
  },
  {
    title: 'Design',
    category: ['Designer', 'Web Developer'],
  },
];
  const categoryoptions = category.map(el=>{
   return <button onClick={()=>setUserSelectedCategory(prev=>{...prev, el})}>{el}</button>
//Now each time a user clicks on a button, we can compare the userSelectedCategory array to the individual job category array.
  });
```

So my approach was to do something like this:

```js
//This value is set whenever a user searches in search bar
const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState(''); 
const pattern = new RegExp('\\b' + keyword.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, ''), 'i');
const filteredjobs = jobs?.filter(
  (job) =>
    (keyword === '' && category.length === 0) ||
    (category.some((el) => job.category.includes(el)) &&
      pattern.test(job.title))
);
```

So the HTML would look like this:

```html
<div>
 <input onChange={e=>setKeyword(e.target.value)} />
 {categoryoptions}
 {filteredjobs}
</div>
```

But the issue with this is that if no categories are selected, then nothing will get returned as default.

So to explain how I want my filter to work,
I want all of the jobs to be displayed if the keyword is blank (input is empty). But if the input is not empty, I want to filter by that value.
In addition, I want it to filter by category even if the keyword is blank.
Lastly, I want it to filter by keyword and by category and both of them are not empty.

Comment: ***I want it to filter by category even if the keyword is blank.*** How can you perform a filter on category if there's no keyword?

Comment: If there is no keyword and the category is empty, I return everything,

Comment: The keyword only filters by the job title, and the jobs are also filtered by the category array, by comparing the category in memory, to the category arrray that is stred to each job

Comment: But your `category` is initialized to an array in the `useState([...])`

Comment: Ok I'm gonna make a small edit to clarify, whats going on with the category array

Answer (score 0):

use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) in place of `{filteredjobs}`:

```
<input value={keyword} onChange={e => setKeyword(e.target.value)} />
{keyword ? filteredjobs : jobs}
```